# Passing parameters in addition to data received from http request, to a method in angularJS

Tags: angularjs, json, api, service, promise

I have this method in my controller that get a json file from my API.

```
      $scope.get = function (code) {

          api.get(code)
              .then(onJsonPart, onError);
      };
```

Doing this:

```
      function onJsonPart(json) {

          console.log(json);
      }
```

I can print out the JSON I received, but I want to pass multiple variables to the onJsonPart method. Something like:

```
      $scope.get = function (code) {

          api.get(code)
              .then(onJsonPart(code, data), onError);
      };
```

Here I get ERROR: data is not defined obviously, question is how do I define the data variable with the data received.

and then have two parameters for my onJsonPart function like this:

```
      function onJsonPart(code, json) {

          console.log('Code: ' + code);
          console.log('json:');
          console.log(json);
      }
```

Comment: It is callback function which take only one param but ill suggest to add your custom variable and values in http service response object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code below will pass `code`and the API's answer `res` to `onJsonPart()`:

```
  $scope.get = function (code) {

      api.get(code)
          .then(
              function(res) {
                  //...some place for logic
                  onJsonPart(code, res);
              },
              function (err) {
                  //...some place for logic
                  onError(err));
              }
      );
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
api.get(code)
.then(function (json) {
    onJsonPart(code, data);
}, onError);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
$scope.get = function (code) {
      api.get(code)
          .then(function(data) {
             onJsonPart(code, data)...
          }
  };
```